# Issue in PostNord Delivery Checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am using **PostNord Delivery Checkout** module downloaded from https://marketplace.magento.com/vconnect-module-allinone.html.

I have configured all required settings in backend and i can see Postnord in Shipping methods list in checkout page working properly. but i cannot find anyway to see tracking information as they have shown in below image

[image: Tracking information]

I have already contacted support of this module but there is no answer yet so just looking for somebody who have used this module and can help me out in this!